# Auth::user() always return null

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-9

recently I have installed spatie/permissions in a fresh Laravel 9 installation. before I install this package whenever I called **Auth::user()** it returns back with the result with the currently authenticated user. but now after I installed spatie/permissions it always returns null in any controller, but it's working normally in views.

is there anyone have the same issue here. and how he managed to fix it.

Comment: "It used to work, but now it doesn't" needs more technical detail. Is there some aspect of these add-ons that conflicts? Does rolling back the changes make it work again?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by clearing the config cache

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Then i would check you have published the config file and set up the settings correctly. If you've modified the config file at all, try returning it to the default settings.

I've never experienced this issue before, the spatie package doesn't normally change the Auth, just the access roles/permissions that you have to add to the code

One other thing to note, each role/permission has a `guard` associated with it. Ensure it's the default guard